# How to return the result from the asynctask to an activity in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have created a Login activity which uses another class - LoginService which is an AsyncTask for the network communication.

```
 public void onClick(View view) {

            if (editTextPassword.getText().toString() != null & editTextUsername.getText().toString() != null){

                new LoginService(editTextUsername.getText().toString(), editTextPassword.getText().toString()).execute();

                if(loginSuccess!=false){
                //Used to move to the Cases Activity
                Intent casesActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CasesActivity.class);
                startActivity(casesActivity);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Incorrect Details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
             }
            else{
                //Display Toaster for error
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter your details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Before the LoginService has finished executing, the activity has already moved  to another activity via the Intent variable. I do not understand why. The idea of the LoginService is to validate the credentials of the user. If it returns true, then it can switch to the other activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want to do this in this way. The `.execute()` will begin as soon as possible, but there is no guarantee (and perhaps guaranteed *not* to) that it will get your `loginSuccess` value back to you in time.

Everything after `new LoginService(...).execute();` should be moved into `onPostExecute()`:

```
private Context mContext = null;
public void setContext(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    if(loginSuccess!=false){
        //Used to move to the Cases Activity
        Intent casesActivity = new Intent(mContext, CasesActivity.class);
        startActivity(casesActivity);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Incorrect Details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Then, you have to call `setContext()` like so:

```
LoginService service = new LoginService(editTextUsername.getText().toString(), editTextPassword.getText().toString());
service.setContext(getApplicationContext());
service.execute();
```

Comment: Okay, thx for the information. But I get an error with the "getApplicationContext()" in the intent code line. How do I create a context from the asyncTask class?

Comment: Ah, I usually keep `AsyncTask`s as inner classes so they can associate well. What you could do is make a `.setContext()` function of `LoginService`, then call that before `execute()` and store it as a member variable. If you'd like, I can edit my post to go into more detail.

Comment: Yes please. I never used or understood the concept of context before. This would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should move

```
Intent casesActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CasesActivity.class);
            startActivity(casesActivity);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Incorrect Details",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

into LoginService's onPostExecute.

In this way you are sure the asynctask has finished its work.

In any case it's quite strange the other activity gets started, it might be because of an old assignement of loginSuccess to true

Answer (score 1):

> How to return the result from the asynctask?

Catch the result of `AsyncTask` from `onPostExecute()`.

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
{
    boolean loginSuccess = result;

    if(loginSuccess!=false) { 

         Intent casesActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CasesActivity.class);
         startActivity(casesActivity);
    }
    else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Incorrect Details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

The data type of result in AsyncTask depends on the 3rd Type parameter.

Sometimes we think `execute()` method of `AsyncTask` will return a result which is wrong. It will return an `AsyncTask` itself

Comment: Thx. But I have an issue now with the argument of getApplicationContext() for the Intent. 

I do not quite understand the purpose of context.

Comment: They are both instances of `Context`, but the application instance is tied to the lifecycle of the application, while the Activity instance is tied to the lifecycle of an `Activity`. You can pass context in `AsyncTask`